# What are possible causes of "Class 'DOMImplementation' not found" errors?

Tags: php, libxml2

I am having issues with a module, which uses PHP's DOM extension via the [CFPropertyList library](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList), to a client's server. Attempting to run the module ends in a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMImplementation' not found in /server/path/here/CFPropertyList/CFPropertyList.php on line 377

The client's server is pretty seriously out-of-date (Apache 2.2.3, PHP 5.2.6, etc.), which is another battle on another front that I will probably lose. However, PHP's documentation of the [DOMImplementation class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domimplementation.php) indicates support was added in PHP 5, so 5.2.6 should be good enough despite being years behind (right?).

Looking at the output of `phpinfo()` suggests `libxml` is installed and enabled, which put the kibosh on my other theory.

**libxml** section of `phpinfo()` output:

```
libXML support  active  
libXML Version  2.6.26  
libXML streams  enabled
```

What other causes could I be looking at to explain this error?

Comment: I had this on Ubuntu 16.04, and what I needed to do was install the php-xml package. Thought I'd mention that as a quick thing to try for anyone on the same platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM might have been disabled at compile time (for a compiled installation) using the `--disable-dom` switch.

Or, in the case of a pre-compiled PHP binary (e.g.: installed using apt, yum, rpm, alien, dpkg, etc.), the DOM extension was not installed, or disabled. Look for `dom.so` file and a matching entry in your php.ini.

`libxml` may be installed, but it doesn't mean that DOM is.

Comment: I missed the `--disable-dom` compile-time directive in my scan of `phpinfo()`. Thanks!